# Jedis: Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: java, spring, heroku, redis, jedis

Following the [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis#spring-xml) of Installing Redis with Spring Java application on Heroku, when the code is deployed on the server, logs show the error:

```
Bean property 'maxActive' is not writable or has an invalid setter method
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

context.xml

```
<beans:bean class="java.net.URI" id="redisUrl">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['REDIS_URL']}"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <beans:property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
    <beans:property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
    <beans:property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jedisPool" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="jedisPoolConfig"/>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="redisUrl"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

The new version of Jedis changed **maxActive** to **maxTotal**

Replace **maxActive** with **maxTotal**

```
<beans:bean id="jedisPoolConfig" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig">
    <beans:property name="maxTotal" value="10"/>
    <beans:property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
    <beans:property name="minIdle" value="1"/>
</beans:bean>
```